# How to append item to list of different column in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dic = {'A':['PINCO','PALLO','CAPPO','ALLOP'],
       'B':['KILO','KULO','FIGA','GAGO'],
       'C':[['CAL','GOL','TOA','PIA','STO'],
            ['LOL','DAL','ERS','BUS','TIS'],
            ['PIS','IPS','ZSP','YAS','TUS'],
            []]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

My goal is to insert for each row the element of `A` as first item of the list contained in column `C`. At the same time I want to set the element of `B` as last item of the list contained in `C`.

I was able to achieve my goal by using the following lines of code:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        row['C'].insert(0,row['A'])
        row['C'].append(row['B'])
    except:
        pass
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to achieve my goal maybe using some Pandas function? I would like to avoid for loops possibly.

Comment: You can do this `df1.C = df1.apply(lambda x: [x.A] + x.C + [x.B], axis=1)`, which is bit nicer, but it's NOT really efficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good general rule is to avoid using `apply` with `axis=1` if at all possible as iterating over the rows is expenisve

You can convert each element in columns A and B to a list with `map` and then sum across the rows.

```
df1['A'] = df1.A.map(lambda x: [x])  
df1['B'] = df1.B.map(lambda x: [x])
df1.sum(1)
CPU times: user 3.07 s, sys: 207 ms, total: 3.27 s
```

The alternative is to use `apply` with axis=1 which ran 15 times slower on my computer on 1 million rows

```
df1.apply(lambda x: [x['A']] + x['C'] + [x['B']], 1)
CPU times: user 48.5 s, sys: 119 ms, total: 48.6 s
```

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Ted's solution but without modifying columns `A` and `B`:

```
def tolist(value):
    return [value]

df1.C = df1.A.map(tolist) + df1.C + df1.B.map(tolist)
```

Using `apply`, you would not write an explicit loop:

```
def modify(row):
    row['C'][:] = [row['A']] + row['C'] + [row['B']]

df1.apply(modify, axis=1)
```

Comment: `df1.A.map(tolist) + df1.C + df1.B.map(tolist)` +1

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `df1.values.tolist()`

```
pd.Series([[r[0]] + r[2] + [r[1]] for r in df1.values.tolist()], df1.index)

0    [PINCO, CAL, GOL, TOA, PIA, STO, KILO]
1    [PALLO, LOL, DAL, ERS, BUS, TIS, KULO]
2    [CAPPO, PIS, IPS, ZSP, YAS, TUS, FIGA]
3                             [ALLOP, GAGO]
dtype: object
```

---

***time testing***

[image]