# append column to another list-like column in same dataframe

Tags: pandas

Consider following dataframe and the need to merge A and B in an expanded list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[['abc', 'def'], 'zzz']] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])

            A    B
0  [abc, def]  zzz
1  [abc, def]  zzz
2  [abc, def]  zzz
```

`add` (or `+`) won't work as-is because `B` is a string so I am doing so:

```
df.A = df.A.add(df.B.apply(lambda x: [x]))
df.drop(['B'], axis=1)

                 A
0  [abc, def, zzz]
1  [abc, def, zzz]
2  [abc, def, zzz]
```

but I was wondering if there is a better (performing) way.

I could not find a one-liner built-in method to add values of a Series to an existing list-like Series. It seems you always must `apply()` to a list first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] + [x['B']], axis=1).to_frame('A')
```

Comment: This is a nice one-liner, you can alternatively write as follows: `df.apply(lambda x: x[0] + [x[1]], axis=1)`

Comment: Performance of `apply()` with `axis=1` is off the chart as it loops through all rows. Using the df in my answer, it took 31s ...

Answer (score 1):

@Yannick,

You could do this:

```py
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.DataFrame([[['abc', 'def'], ['zzz']]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
   df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'] 
   print(df)
```

Comment: You are changing the hypothesis - B is a string, not a list of string. If both columns were lists, I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763997/how-to-append-item-to-list-of-different-column-in-pandas - I found this to be relevant, but they are always using the same approach as you

Comment: Thanks ! Had not found that related question

Answer (score 1):

You may use the help from numpy reshape

```
df.A.add(df.B.values[:,None].tolist())

Out[81]:
0    [abc, def, zzz]
1    [abc, def, zzz]
2    [abc, def, zzz]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here some time testing based on answers so far and [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763997/how-to-append-item-to-list-of-different-column-in-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[['abc', 'def'], 'zzz']] * 2**20, columns=['A', 'B'])

%timeit df.A.add(df.B.apply(lambda x: [x]))
%timeit df.A.add(df.B.map(lambda x: [x]))
%timeit df.A.add(df.B.values[:,None].tolist())
%timeit pd.Series([r[0] + [r[1]] for r in df.values.tolist()])

1 loop, best of 3: 321 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 374 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 313 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 476 ms per loop
```

So not much differences.